# Support for Bit Vector Size Limit > 2^31 -1 in R?

Tags: r, vector, size, bit

I have been quite interested lately with extremely large vectors/arrays in R. I know from reading the documentation that the size limit of an array is *2<sup>31</sup> - 1*.  However, using the CRAN package "bit", it is possible to instantiate a vector of booleans of length *n* while only using *n/32* bits.  I was wondering if it was possible to overcome R's internal limits by somehow implementing bit vectors (or some other way).  It seems, to me, that it should be possible to have a bit vector with a limit of 32 times the maximum size (i.e. *32(2<sup>31</sup> - 1) = 2<sup>5</sup>(2<sup>31</sup> - 1)*). I have tried a variety of methods, however unsuccessfully.  Below are some examples that R can handle:

```
library("bit")
a <- as.bit(rep(T, 10))
a
bit length=100 occupying only 4 integers
   1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8        93   94   95  96   97   98   99  100 
TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE   .. TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE

a <- as.bit(rep(T, 10^9))
```

Here are some examples that throw R into a panic:

```
b <- as.bit(rep(T, 10^10))
Error in rep(T, 10^10) : invalid 'times' argument
In addition: Warning message:
In as.bit(rep(T, 10^10)) : NAs introduced by coercion

a <- c(as.bit(rep(T, 10^9)), as.bit(rep(T, 10^9)), as.bit(rep(T, 10^9)), as.bit(rep(T, 10^9)), as.bit(rep(T, 10^9)))
Error in if (length%%.BITS) n <- length%/%.BITS + 1L else n <-     length%/%.BITS : 
argument is not interpretable as logical
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In sum(nold) : integer overflow - use sum(as.numeric(.))
2: In c.bit(as.bit(rep(T, 10^9)), as.bit(rep(T, 10^9)), as.bit(rep(T,  :
integer overflow in 'cumsum'; use 'cumsum(as.numeric(.))'
```

Edit:  After doing some research, I have found that the restriction on vector size is due to the restriction on integers.  The maximum integer allowed by R is *2<sup>31</sup> - 1* and since integers are used for indexing vectors, we impose the same size limits on them.  This still doesn't really answer my question.  As the first example indicates above, I have a bit vector with 100 boolean items in it that is only taking up 4 integers worth of memory.  Is there some sort of way of nesting indices?  For example, to see the 83rd element in the 1<sup>st</sup> bit vector, could we do something like a[2][19] (2*32 + 19 = 83) for bit vectors?

Comment: R supports vectors longer than 2^32 - 1; see `news(grepl("LONG VECTORS", Category))`. Often one wants to manipulate large data in parallel, which implies managing memory, e.g., processing data in chunks, so long vectors may not be a good solution.

Comment: That is really helpful, although it doesn't really get to the heart of my problem. I am simply curious, whatever the vector limit is (even if it was _2^100000 - 1_), as to the possibilities of circumventing these limits by using bit vectors. See my edited response above.

Comment: Still not answering your question, but you're not correct in saying that vectors are limited by the size of integers; the index can be a floating point number, allowing exact indexing up to 2^52 elements (that's a very big number).

Comment: The error you see above is actually a limitation of the bit package; contact `maintainer("bit")` and perhaps they will address it.