# data.frame not accepting a vector of length 2^32

Tags: r

In R I can create a vector of length 2^32 but then when I try to create a dataframe with that vector as a column it errors

this works

```
a = vector(mode="logical", length = 2^32)
```

this fails

```
adf = data.frame(a)
```

> Error in if (mirn && nrows[i] > 0L) { :    missing value where
>   TRUE/FALSE needed In addition: Warning message: In attributes(.Data)
>   <- c(attributes(.Data), attrib) :   NAs introduced by coercion to
>   integer range

I am using 64bit Windows and I have lots of RAM (64G) so I should be able to store it. What's wrong?

Comment: 64bit Windows 7 here as well: First line works only up to power of 30 but i guess thats purely my poor ram capacity. Second line works, but as Rich wrote, conditional on first line. So cant reproduce here. Just FYI :)

Comment: @BigDataScientist yeah u need more ram sounds lik

Comment: Something similar has been filed as an [open unconfirmed bug](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=16927).

Comment: what is your `memory.limit()`

Comment: I just tried it with ```as.data.frame``` and it worked in transforming ```a``` to a dataframe. Not sure about the error though.

Comment: @Kim try to inspect the result of as.data.frame. Try assessing the vector using adf[1]; it gave an error. So it didn't work, just that it didn't throw an error, so you thought it worked.

Comment: @Headpoint 64000

Comment: Ah, you are right---for ```dim(a)``` I got NA, 1. I think the size limit on R internally is 2^31-1. If you tinker around, you will see that it works for 2^30. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28398007/support-for-bit-vector-size-limit-231-1-in-r) for instance.